# Tesseract does not recognize single characters

Tags: ocr, tesseract

How to represent:

1. Create new image with paint (any size)
2. Add letter A to this image
3. Try to recognize -> tesseract will not find any letters
4. Copy-paste this letter 5-6 times to this image
5. Try to recognize -> tesseract will find all the letters

Why?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You must set the "page segmentation mode" to "single char".

For example, in Android you do the following:

```
api.setPageSegMode(TessBaseAPI.pageSegMode.PSM_SINGLE_CHAR);
```

Comment: Thanks! Setting `PageSegMode.SingleChar`  fixed the issue.

Comment: `api.SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_SINGLE_CHAR);` for C++ users ;)

Comment: The equivalent command line parameter: `--psm 10`

Comment: `engine.DefaultPageSegMode = PageSegMode.SingleChar;` for C# users (engine is TesseractEngine)

Answer (score 15):

python code to do that configuration is like this:

```
import pytesseract
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("path to some image")
pytesseract.image_to_string(
     img, config=("-c tessedit"
                  "_char_whitelist=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
                  " --psm 10"
                  " -l osd"
                  " "))
```

the `--psm` flag defines the page segmentation mode.

according to documentaion of tesseract, `10` means :

> Treat the image as a single character.

so to recognize a single character you just need to use : `--psm 10` flag.

Answer (score 10):

You need to set Tesseract's page segmentation mode to "single character."

Comment: Well, it depends entirely on how you're using tesseract.  If you're calling it from the shell, you would say `tesseract $image $outbase -psm 10`.  The -psm sets the page segmentation mode, and mode 10 is for single characters.  It's all in the man page.

Comment: In some cases, mode 13 works better. Alternatively make the image smaller/larger might help.

Comment: setting the psm to 10 does not seem to make a difference.  My use case is a single large character on a larger white background.  A clear 'A' in this example yields '-\n' with a psm of 10 at 200 DPI.

Answer (score 7):

Have you seen this?

https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=581

The bug list shows it as "no longer an issue".

- Be sure to have high resolution images.
- If you are resizing the image, be sure to keep a high DPI and don't resize too small
- Be sure to [train your tesseract system](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract)
- use the `baseApi.setVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");` code before the `init Tesseract`
- Also, you may look into [which font to use with OCR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316068/what-is-the-ideal-font-for-ocr)