# Tesseract can't recognize simple numbers

Tags: ocr, tesseract

[image]

```
$ tesseract pin3.png output
$ cat output.txt


bon 9 no Us

(oe


// expect 

391 
205
786
 4
```

I think the image is not complicated, but `tesseract` doesn't recognize the numbers of image. I thought perhaps number's colors are white, so I tried to change number color to black but result is same. How can I make `tesseract` recognize that kinds of image?

Thanks

-- As you can see, This is not single word

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tesseract does not recognize single characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632044/tesseract-does-not-recognize-single-characters)

Comment: While suggested link doesn't provide correct answer - it says right thing. Try different `psm` - page segmentation modes (see [tesseract wiki](\\nlbawfps1\BI_Prod_Support_TransferToDev) for more info about psm)

Comment: @DmitriiZ. I tried `psm 0 to 13` but all of them failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preprocess image:

1. invert
2. binarize

[image]

```
tesseract numpad_.png - --psm 6
Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.
3 9 1
2 0 5
7 8 6

4
```

Comment: That "Invert" really helped OCR, so it will have white background and black text. Went from totally clear numbers, and couldn't translate a thing, to translating everything easily. Thank you!!